# how is send to android to arduino char

Tags: android, arduino, char, tracking, face

I want to track to face with android - i amde it at computer - now i want to at ndroid. arduino program controlled pan and tilt servos. i must be send to arduino only one char example "w" so arduino make it +1 move servo or etc. I can't send to arduino that char.

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
        mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
        if (mJavaDetector != null)
            mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                    new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }
    else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
        if (mNativeDetector != null)
            mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
    }

    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
        Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
    for( int i=0; i<facesArray.length; i++ ) {
        rect( facesArray[i].x, facesArray[i].y, facesArray[i].width, facesArray[i].height ); 

    if(facesArray[i].x  < 640){
        arduinoPort.write("w");
    // println("left"); 
    //moutput.write("d");
        //mOutputStream.write("d".toString());  

   } 

    if(facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width > 1280){
        //println("right"); 
        arduinoPort.write("a");
       }

    if(facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height > 640){
        //println("bottom"); 
        arduinoPort.write("s");
       }

    if(facesArray[i].y < 320){
         //  println("top"); 
           arduinoPort.write("w");
          }

    if ((facesArray[i].x > 640) && (facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width < 1280)){
        //println("center"); 
           arduinoPort.write("z");

          }
    return mRgba;
```

**this is a arduino code**

```
    #include <Max3421e.h> 
    #include <Usb.h> 
    #include <AndroidAccessory.h> 
    #include <Servo.h> 

      Servo WristServo;  
      Servo BaseServo;
    int tilt = 90;
    int pan = 90;
    void setup() 
     { 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WristServo.attach(11);
    BaseServo.attach(12);
    WristServo.write(tilt);  
    BaseServo.write(pan);  
 } 

 void loop() 
 { 
  if(Serial.available() > 0)  
 {
 int data = Serial.read();  
 switch(data)
 {

  case 'w' : if (pan > 0) {pan -=1;} break;
   case 's' : if (pan > 0) {pan +=1;} break;
 case 'a' : if (tilt < 180) {tilt -=1;} break;
 case 'd' : if (tilt > 0) {tilt +=1;} break;
  default  : break;
  }

  }

    WristServo.write(tilt);
   BaseServo.write(pan);

}
```

Comment: i added processing.serial library too. but dont move servos. dont send anything from android to arduino. what is problem? already thanks

Comment: Through magic, probably. Or, if you want a more precise answer, please give all the details, answering questions such as "how are the two devices connected?" and "what is `arduinoPort`?" and "what is the arduino doing? post its code" and, assuming you are using a serial connection, "did you check with an oscilloscope? Is the data sent?" and "how did you check that the arduino is not receiving anything?" and any other question you think will be useful to understand your problem. Please edit the question answering these questions (in English pls) and then probably you'll find someone to help you

Comment: man i ask only that how is android code send char to arduino.i think connoisseurs understand my question. :) i will wait them. :).i said i want to send only char with android to arduino. arduinoport.write ("w"); dont work. i said it. what is true way. anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think that with "connoisseurs" you mean people who know you deeply, because I assure you that people who don't know you and/or the system you are building will never be able to understand what the problem is. You didn't even tell how the devices are connected! Are they connected through a serial bluetooth adapter? Through USB-OTG? Wifi? Wifi+ethernet? Internet? Proprietary protocols? Each of them has a deeply different approach and should be implemented in different ways. So what is the connection you are using? And if you answer the questions I wrote instead of making us guess the [...]

Comment: [...] answers you will get faster answers

Comment: man i said android-arduino connection that program is android. so usb-otg connected with arduino-android. i dont new but i dont expert too. so i want to help. :) what code should be written in my program.

Comment: The most usual way to connect arduino and android is by bluetooth, so that "so usb-otg" is not so obvious. Then you also missed a lot of other questions, like "how do you notice that the arduino does not receive the command? If you don't see any movement, try to increment the "increment" (i mean pan += 10 instead of 1)

Comment: this program work with personel computer with opencvprocessing program.now, i want to work from android.But I'll try your suggestions too.thanks for help.

Comment: nobody is here :((

Comment: Listen, I tried to tell you in any possible way, but you don't want to listen. So I'll just write it once more for you: if you want any answer, you have to ask a question. So, give the details. I suggested you a lot of information you didn't give but are necessary, so you just have to answer those questions (writing the answers in the original question), otherwise NO ONE will be able to guess what you mean and so to try and give you any solution. The proof? 1 week and still no answer. And changing tags does not help: if there is no **real** question, there could be no **real** answer

Comment: i added arduino code. and my question very clear. man, i gave details. i want to send from android to arduino "only char". like "w" then arduino send to make servo move. thats it.. you can look at arduino code. dont receive anything from arduino to android too. just send from android to arduino. :(

Comment: Ok, I give up... In my first comment I wrote a lot of questions; after 1 week and 3 more comments I haven't seen the answer to any of those questions, so.. I just give up..